# Php line break in csv does not work

Tags: php, csv, break

I build a csv with php,

but at the moment I have the problem that it will not break the line in the .csv file.

I have this:

```
$users = $row['COL 1']."".$row['COL 2']."".$row['COL 3']."".$row['COL 4'];
```

This is what I tried:

```
$users = $row['COL 1']."\n\r".$row['COL 2']."\n\r".$row['COL 3']."\n\r".$row['COL 4'];
```

I want to get after the line break a new column not a new row.
Something like this:

```
  | A                          |
__|____________________________|
1 | name 1 <-line break here   |
  | name 2 <- this shall happen|
_______________________________|
```

but it did not work, please need some help:)

Comment: Why aren't you using PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function?

Comment: If you look on it in a browser notice that you cannot see the line breaks, in this case put `header("content-type: text/plain")` on top

Comment: @PhilippDahse doesn't matter how to open the file, new lines inside a cell need to be escaped or otherwise they will corrupt the whole table.